# You may now start monero-wallet-cli. What should do I next?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

My monero says  "You are now synchronized with the network. You may now start monero-wallet-cli" then I started "monero-wallet-cli" but it shows Starting Refresh... 
I tried to start mining with 'start_mining' command but it says insert wallet address `<addr> [<threads>]`
I have my wallet address, I tried to copy and paste but it doesn't work, and what is THREADS? How check my wallet is correct to mined? 
What commands need to do next?

Comment: try downloading the gui wallet https://getmonero.org/2017/03/29/monero-gui-beta-2-released.html you can run a node, use the wallet, and mine all in the same place without using commands. THREADS=the number of threads your cpu has which can increase mining performance

Answer (score 1):

I was need to start my wallet 1st and then typed: 'start_mining 4' 
It solved my problem started mining with using 4 CPUs, don't need add command from 'monerod'